# xbindkeys to remap extra mouse buttons

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, mouse, xbindkeys

I'm following [this tutorial](https://blog.hanschen.org/2009/10/13/mouse-shortcuts-with-xbindkeys/) but cant seem to get this working

I used xev and confirmed the two mouse buttons I want to map are button 8 and button 9

I want to map them to the "a" and "s" keys on the keyboard.

I tried the following variations in my .xbindkeysrc but it doesn't do anything when I click my mouse buttons (I confirmed that remapping keyboard keys to commands like "xterm" does work).

```
"a"
  b:8

m:0x0 + c:38
  b:8

xte 'key a'
  b:8


xte 'key 0x61'
  b:8
```

Also tried these variations with "b:8 + release"

Nothing is working not sure why

Comment: [Solved] by mapping mouse buttons to keyboard keys via xkbset: see Use keys for mouse buttons on linux. Alternative to AHK? https://superuser.com/questions/313926/use-keys-for-mouse-buttons-on-linux-alternative-to-ahk

Answer (score 2):

The format for `~/.xbindkeysrc` is:

```
"command to execute"
  keys
```

You want to execute the command `xte 'key 0x61'`, because this command simulates a press of the key <kbd>a</kbd>, so you need

```
"xte 'key 0x61'"
  b:2
```

(That's probably the only variation you didn't try...). Putting anything execept a shell command between the double quotes, like `a` or `m:0x0 + c:38`, make no sense: `xbindkeys` would try to execute that just if you typed it in a shell, and of course that's not a sensible Linux command like `xte`. Likewise, using commands without double quotes won't work.

Answer (score 0):

type `$ xev | sed -ne '/^KeyPress/,/^$/p'` and catch the unicode for your keyboard keypress; for example, letter <kbd>a</kbd> unicode is `0x61`.

Then, edit `~/.xbindkeysrc` and add your own shortcut at the end of the file as following:

```
#Comment of what the binding (is doing)/(is for)
"xdotool key <target key>"
       <source key>
```

E.g.,:

```
#Switch Workspaces
"xdotool key 'super+0xff09'"
        b:2
```

Finally, don't forget to make `$xbindkeys -p` to update the conf used.